# Jenkins/Tomcat - First deploy/start always fails, second deploy/start works

Tags: java, tomcat, jenkins, war

we've got a confusing problem here: We have a jenkins deploy build (via jenkins-deploy plugin) that deploys to a tomcat 8.5 (without context path specified). Nothing fancy here, just a .war file to be deployed to tomcat.

The first deployment always fails, or, to be more exact, the deployment succeeds, but the starting of the app fails:

> org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.TomcatManagerException:
>   FAIL - Deployed application at context path /jive-framework-1.2.0-RC8
>   but context failed to start

The second deployment (of the same app) then works flawlessly (the app can be started, too).

Anyone got an idea why the first start doesn't work?

Comment: What does your logs say about the startup failure?

Comment: org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.TomcatManagerException: FAIL - Deployed application at context path /my-application-1.2.0-RC8 but context failed to start

Comment: Wow, that's really a lot of information. Could you tell your tomcat to be a little bit more detailed? [Tomcat 8.5 logging](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/logging.html). My suspicion is that this is due to the missing context path.

Comment: You need to post more from the stacktrace.

Comment: My bad, sorry. It seemed that the server only started the second time, but actually it was random, just accidentally every second time in the test, because of a Set that prevented correct server startup.